# CasperJS + Heroku : invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: heroku, casperjs

I run a CasperJS script in heroku, but heroku reports:

```
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    Command:     heroku run casperjs testing.js
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.25.0 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
    Error ID:    a519228772c040d788af55b660c13be7
```

I checked other questions in SO, I found that the error is probably sent out by Ruby.

How can I prevent this error?

p.s. The program is to fetch some information from some Chinese sites. Some data are fetched, but some can't. It encounters this error **randomly** (double check by executing the same command for few times)

Answer (score 0):

[E.J. Finneran](https://github.com/ejfinneran) found [a workaround](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/549) for this with converting the data to base64 (see bottom of the github thread).

I'll repeat his solution here:

```
heroku run 'replicate -r ./config/environment -d "Post.all" | base64'  > base64_file

# Clean up the base64_file since heroku flattens STDERR to STDOUT so you'll have some junk lines at the top

base64 -i base64file -D > binary_file
replicate -r ./config/environment -l < binary_file
```